# Non-Comulative nature of Mass-Radius curves of Neutron Stars

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, neutron-stars

For finding the mass-radius curve of neutron stars, we can solve [TOV Equations](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation) which are constraint equations got by solving Einsteins equations. The boundary conditions are $m(r=0)=0$ and $\rho(r=0)=\rho_c$. Then we put a physical condition that for $r\rightarrow r_*$(radius of star), $\rho\rightarrow 0$, and by this we can get the limiting radius $r_*$ and mass $m_*$ and plots like[image: Mass Radius curve for TOV polytropic neutron star]

and for density

[image]

I understood and took it from [MIT OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-962-general-relativity-spring-2020/resources/ps10/)

One can also do the same process for Modified Gravities and more involved $P(\rho)$ matter equations

- I have seen many places where the mass-radius curve looks like

[image]

This curve is from the paper ["Neutron stars in Einstein-Λ gravity: the cosmological constant effects
G. H. Bordbar1,
, S. H. Hendi1, and B. Eslam Panah"](https://arxiv.org/)

- **Confusion**: Why isn't the mass of neutron star cumulative as radius increases, i.e. it must be $0$ at $r=0$ and reach its maximum at $r=r_*$? Maybe I am not getting the right interpretation of these curves. So, I would be grateful for some explanation or references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your non-cumulative curves relate the total mass of the star to its surface radius. Different points represent different stars.

Your cumulative curves relate enclosed mass of a star versus radius of the shell enclosing the mass. Different points represent different radii within a given star.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! So the perimeter is the central density to plot this curve??

Comment: @user235005 I'm not sure. For the curve you showed, the star's radius is the x-axis, usually used for the independent variable. So, I'd guess they used a density of zero at that radius as the boundary condition.

Comment: What can be the other perimeters for which we can draw the ($M_* - R_*$) curve? Bcoz $M_*, R_*$ is the result of solving TOV equations with initial conditions and a physical boundary constraint. So I guess the change in initial condition i.e. central density might be the perimeter!